# Symfony create new object many to one error call undefined method

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, many-to-one

I have set up a many to one relation and want to add a new product-object linked to its category. Related to this I have 2 questions:

I get stuck on saving the category object to the new product. Tried different options and read related questions here. At this moment I am getting the error: 
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getCategory" of class "AppBundle\Controller\ProductController".
I do have the method getCategory in my Product class. 
What am I missing here?

Another thing I would like to know is do I need to pass the category-id in the url to get the related products for that category?

I have a category class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $cat_id;
 ... 
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
*/
private $products; ...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new ArrayCollection(); 
}
```

and product class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $prd_id;

    /**
     * @var Category
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="cat_id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;

    ....

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
```

From my list of categories "/categories" I link the categories to the productlist  "/cat1/product" (<-- do I need to pass the category-id here?). There I want to add a new product and call the following action in my ProductController:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Form\ProductType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/cat{cat_id}/product/new", name="newproduct")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, $cat_id)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $category = $this->getCategory();
            $product->setCategory($category);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('productlist');
        }

        return $this->render('product/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'cat_id' => $cat_id,
            ));
    }
```

Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do :

```
    $category = $this->getCategory();
```

$this represent your productController, it is the reason of the undefined method error. to get the category object you must do :

```
     $categoryRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
     $product->setCategory($categoryRepository->find($cat_id));
```

hope that may help you.

Comment: Indeed this helps. I somehow expected the getter "Get category" in the product entity would do this for me because of the many-to-one link. But as I understand now this is not the case. Another thing I would like to know is do I need to pass the category-id in the url to get the related products for that category?

Comment: you can add a select hydrated by all of your categories in the product form. You can see the good way here [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: Since I allready selected a category before adding a new product I dont want to select a category again. I am looking for a (easy) way to pass the category id from the category controller to the product controller without having to pass it through the url.